# What is the default font color in Plotly go.Table?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

What is the default font color for Plotly go.Table?
This
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67844390/5539732 answer references https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-font but this does not appear correct. I'm using Plotly for python in Google Colab.

Snippet of default color below:

[image: Example image of default color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may vary with your Plotly version. I'm on `5.3.1`, and running a [`go.Table()`](https://plotly.com/python/table/) example in `JupyterLab v2.1.5` produces the table below. And you can check the fontcolor of the cells if you first use `f = fig.full_figure_for_development()` and then

```
f.data[0].cells.font.color
```

Which returns:

```
'#2a3f5f'
```

#### Table:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                 cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                     ])
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
print(f.data[0].cells.font.color)
fig.show()
```

Comment: That answers my question, I wasn't aware of `fig.full_figure_for_development()` I'm having issues with plotly finding/installing kaleido but that is another issue I'll have to look into.