# How to use an own font with plotly

Tags: python, fonts, plotly

Is it possible to use an installed font on your PC for the fonts in your plotly-plot?

Or differently asked, can you add a font to a library like plotly?
thanks

Comment: This [What is the default font in Python Plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67844335/what-is-the-default-font-in-python-plotly) may also be helpful.

Comment: It looks like you cant. https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/polar/