# Set default font family in Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, font-face, plotly.js

Is there a way to globally set the default font family for Plotly.js?
Currently it defaults to 'Open Sans', 'Verdana', 'sans-serif', but I would like to override that within an application to use different font stacks.

From the Plotly.js source code I can see that the default font stack is hard coded in a few places, particularly `src/plots/layout_attributes.js`.

Might there a way to "monkey patch" the default value of `font-family` in JS?   I would like to avoid needing to create a new fork of the repo, and use the latest CDN versions.

[image]

Below are the attributes that I can see within the browser dev console, but I don't see a way to access `globalFont.family.dflt`

[image]

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3027

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67844335/what-is-the-default-font-in-python-plotly#:~:text=If%20Open%20Sans%20is%20available,serif%20available%20on%20your%20system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67844335/what-is-the-default-font-in-python-plotly#:%7E:text=If%20Open%20Sans%20is%20available,serif%20available%20on%20your%20system).

Comment: @marc_s Good catch and my apology ,I must have pressed submit twice in close succession and created two copies of the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Those layout attributes (defined in `src/plots/layout_attributes.js`) are precisely those we can modify in the layout config (`globalFont` is exported as [`font`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-font)), so you can just do :

```js
const data = [{
// ...
}];

const layout = {
  font: {
    family: '"Open Sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif',
    size: 12,
    color: '#444'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Note we can also apply specific fonts for specific elements, see :

- [`layout.title.font`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-title-font)
- [`layout.legend.font`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-legend-font)
- [`layout.legend.grouptitlefont`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-legend-grouptitlefont)
- [`layout.legend.title.font`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-legend-title-font)
- [`layout.hoverlabel.font`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-hoverlabel-font)

Comment: Thanks!  This is how we're handling it now. But my question is how to set the default font family that Plotly would fall back to if the plot configuration didn't specify them.  For instance, we have many thousands of Plotly chart configurations and I'd like them to appear in different themes for different users without having to override the configs for each.  Analogous to setting style in a class in a CSS file that varies by client, rather than hardcoding fontfamily into every div in HTML `<div style="font-family: <%=brand.font%>">...</div>"`

Comment: Yes, setting the font in the layout is more a way to override the defaults for a specific plot rather than setting those defaults globally, but it seems the latter is not possible. In fact, we _can_ set global settings via `Plotly.setPlotConfig()`, but this function handles only a restricted set of settings (see [plot_config.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js) + 'locale') and the font is not part of it. It would be worth creating a feature request to make plot_config.js define the global font so that the function can handle it as well.